# Can I get the locate to work on Windows through Git Bash?

Tags: windows-7, git-bash

Git Bash seems to have nice support of various Linux commands. It even supports locate, though it never finds anything:

```
mypc@mypc MINGW64 ~
$ locate --regex .*?\/[^\/]+\.docx
```

I tried to update the locate database, but the support is not finished there:

```
mypc@mypc MINGW64 ~
$ updatedb
/usr/bin/updatedb: line 323: /usr/var/locatedb.n: No such file or directory
Failed to generate /usr/var/locatedb.n
```

Can I fix that by editing some script? What causes this problem?

Answer (score 14):

from git bash run:

```
mkdir /c/Program\ Files/Git/usr/var; updatedb --localpaths='/c/'
```

Also you can add the following alias in your ~/.bash_profile:

```
alias updatedb="updatedb --localpaths='/c/'"
```

I havent tried the alias out yet bit I don't see why it would work.

Just make sure to either

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or open a new shell after you have added the alias so it gets loaded.

Comment: See that you must create the `var` subdirectiory where your git is installed. Also add multiple dirs if you have more than one drive with `--localpath='/c/ /d/'`

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the tip!
Just wanted to add to @danielpflood's answer, that I needed to **run** "Git Bash" **as administrator**, to be able to create the needed /var/ directory.
This is on Windows 10.

[*wanted to add as a comment, but I do not have enough reputation for that.*]

Answer (score 2):

I found I needed to create a directory `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\var` and give my user full access to it.

This fixed the permissions issue, but in order to get it to index the correct files I also had to invoke updatedb as `updatedb --localpaths='/c/'` (I imagine this can be put in a config file somewhere)